# Why is my dblclick-Event not triggered reliably while in a jQuery-draggable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have a textarea in a div that I made draggable with jQuery draggable. The textarea is marked readonly. I want to make it editable using a dblclick-Event, but that seems to conflict with the jQuery draggable, because sometimes only one click is necessary and mostly only a tripple click will be sufficient.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

My thought is that your first click is moving slightly when you press the button down. By default JQUI sets the 'distance' attribute to 1px, meaning that if your mouse moves even one pixel while clicking, it triggers the draggable code. Try using this code in your initial .draggable code.

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable({ distance: 30 });
```